# Sort/Order df according to 2 values from another df

Tags: r, sorting

I have 2 df that both contain the same first 2 columns:

date  |symbol| cell3
2010-01-05| AAPB |12300
2010-01-05| AZT |45600
2010-01-05| AUMO |78900

and df 2 (`buys`) with pretty much the same info, but the symbols are not in the same order as df1 (`new_panel`).

I would like to order df2 in the same way that df1 is set up.

I tried `buys[sort(order(buys)[new_panel])]`but it does not seem to work for my case.

Edit:
I need to sort it by date AND symbol.

I also tried this, but it doesn't work for duplicates `require(gdata)`
 `new_panel <- reorder.factor(new_panel$symbol, new.order=buys$symbol)`

Comment: I also tried this with no luck `new_panel[order(match(new_panel,buys))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second data frame has the same information, you can sort that by date and then use `symbol` from the first data frame as a target vector for setting up the second data frame.

```
buys[order((as.Date(buys$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")),match(new_panel$symbol, buys$symbol)),,]
```

Comment: Your fist line of code worked perfectly! Thank you! But unfortunately your second line of code neither gives me an error nor does it sort `new_panel` according to `symbol` from `buys`. Do you have any idea what I could do to omit the error?

Comment: Try this: `buys[order((as.Date(buys$date, format="%Y-%m-%d")),match(new_panel$symbol, buys$symbol)),,]`
It's a combination of the two lines that orders the date first and then the symbol based on `order()` in `base`

Comment: Great work! Thanks!